# What's the simplest way to add vue.js typings to an existing typescript file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've got an existing ASP.NET web site, I'm using Typescript and everything is ticking along nicely.

If I decide I want to use jQuery I can simply run `npm install @types/jQuery`, and suddenly jQuery in all is glory is available to me in my .ts file. If I want to use lodash then `npm install @types/lodash` and without further ado there is my fully typed lodash.

If however I run `npm install @types/vue` then.... nothing. Any reference to Vue in my .ts file gets me `TS2304 (TS) Cannot find name 'Vue'`.

What's going on? I thought Vue was supposed to be one of the most Typescript friendly projects?

Comment: Vue comes with definition files. If you have it installed (with `npm install vue`) it should work (maybe check your module resolution )

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I've tried that but still no joy. I'm not doing anything special with module resolution. For instance if I create a new empty ASP.NET Core Web Application in Visual Studio and do nothing but add a .ts file and `npm install @types/jquery` then that all works, but not with `npm install vue`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the disclaimer in @types/vue https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/vue

> This is a stub types definition for vuejs
>   (https://github.com/vuejs/vue). vuejs provides its own type
>   definitions, so you don't need @types/vue installed!

Your compiler thinks that @types/vue is the right package. But it's probably causing the bug. You can try to remove it. 
If you still can't get the type, you might need to include node_modules/vue into your typing roots

Comment: If I remove all trace of `@types/vue` and instead `npm install vue` the effect is the same, i.e. any use of `Vue` in typescript gets `Cannot find name 'Vue'`.

Comment: You created your project with @vue/cli, right? Probably you have a small configuration issue. I'd recommend to go over https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: No I didn't create the project with @vue/cli. This is a large existing project and I just want to use vue on one of the pages. The last time I did this it was incredibly easy, I just needed to add `/// <reference path="vue.d.ts" />` to the top of my .ts file, but it seems it's all changed since those good old days.

Comment: theoretically you should be able to do the same thing by adding node_modules/vue/types/index.d.ts. But probably you should do the same for router, maybe vuex etc. I think your typeRoots in ts config should be ['./node_modules/@types', "vue/types"]

Comment: `node_modules\vue\types\index.d.ts` does exist, it was added when I ran `npm install vue`, along with `options.d.ts`, `plugin.d.ts`, `vnode.d.ts` and `vue.d.ts`.

Comment: It exists in your node_modules. But it should be visible to tsc. That's why it should be included as one of your type roots in tsconfig

Comment: I added that but no difference unfortunately. Thanks anyway.